# CSV Data Set Config called by a Module Controller

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

I would like to know if it is suposed to a "CSV Data Set Config" element (which is  inside of a Simple Controller from a deactivated ThreadGroup. i.e.: DeactivatedThreadGroup >>> CSV_SimpleController >> CSV Data Set Config) work fine when it is called by a module controller from an active thread group?

I mean, is that something that will prevent the csv lines iteration process? I am not being able to make it work.

Currently what I have is: Thread 'n' reads only the 'n' element from the csv.
Iteration 1
Thread 1 - 1st csv line
Thread 2 - 2nd csv line
Iteration 2
Thread 1 - 1st csv line
Thread 2 - 2nd csv line
Iteration 3
Thread 1 - 1st csv line
Thread 2 - 2nd csv line

I know that if I put the CSV Data Set Config inside of the active thread group it will work fine. I just would like to know if not working when called by a module controller is a limitation of this component. 
Maybe there are something regarding the module controller behaviour that I am not aware of.

Link to the .jmx file:
https://files.fm/u/zu7cyunn

Please, check the images below:

[image: TestPlan]

[image: CSV Data Set Config Module Controller]

[image: CSV Data Set Config]

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using Thread Group, you need to go for [Test Fragment](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#test_fragments) instead. As per JMeter [Functions and Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) User Manual chapter:

> Variables are local to a thread

So given you define them in another Thread Group which basically gets merged into "main" test plan tree the generated variables are not visible to other Thread Groups.

Suggested Test Plan setup:

[image: JMeter Module Controller Test Plan]

More information: [How to Manage Large JMeter Scripts With JMeter Test Fragments](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-manage-large-jmeter-scripts-jmeter-test-fragments)